# Como modificar o caminho do input file?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Boa noite, tenho um campo do tipo file, quando clico nele abre uma caixa de diálogo para que eu possa escolher um arquivo do meu computador.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Ao invés de escolher um arquivo do meu computador, eu gostaria de escolher um arquivo que está dentro de determinada pasta do servidor.

Como posso fazer isso?

Desenvolvo com PHP e jQuery

Comment: Basicamente com um INPUT FILE não sera possível, o input file procura arquivos em seu computador. Você pode criar uma solução com jQuery e PHP listando os arquivos do servidor em um checkbox. Com isso o usuário selecionaria os arquivos que deseja incluir ou processar. Você pode criar interfaces bem atrativas com apenas jQuery e CSS. Para saber mais você pode entrar neste link http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4494793.htm

Comment: Sugiro colocar o comentário do @PedroHenrique como resposta, pois não é possível determinar uma pasta padrão para arquivos de upload em html por múltiplas questões, dentre elas a de segurança do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo Bosquett e Pedro Henrique.

Comment: Rafael, vai ter de criar uma página para mostrar os ficheiros que há no servidor e que simula o menu quando escolhe um ficheiro no seu computador. Se quiser ajuda a fazer isso pode reformular a pergunta com as partes que não sabe fazer para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Olá Sérgio, agradeço pela disposição, estou trabalhando no projeto e assim que surgir mais dúvidas sobre o assunto, com certeza estarei aqui para contar com vocês, muito obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução no windows 7 para seu problema seria configurar o SAMBA e mapear a unidade da rede em seu explorer.
Assim a pasta do servidor ficaria acessivel como, por exemplo (X:)

Answer (score 0):

caso tenha interesse em trabalhar em cima de algo pronto, da uma olhada:

http://elfinder.org/

No mais, ;e o que o @PedroHenrique respondeu.

Abs